# JQuery .toggle() Not understood

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I am newbie to the programming and currently learning through udemy. Having trouble understanding the `toggle()` method logic. I would highly appreciate if anyone could help me understand the following `toggle` method functionality.

I am confused at `var started  = false` I hope it means start only if it is false.

```
 var started = false;
 var level = 0;

 $(document).on("keydown", function(){
  if (!started) {
  $("#level-title").text("Level" + level);
  nextSequence();
  started = true;
 }
})
```

Comment: I don't see any `toggle` method used in this code. Here's an example from [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp). Also you may find an alternate usage of the `toggle` functionality but not exactly the same `program`

Comment: so what is started = false/true ?

Comment: If my answer satisfies you, then go ahead and accept it as it will help others in future.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for assigning the **false** value to the **started** variable is to switch back to **true** on `keydown` event. See the following example:

```js
var showSecondParagraph = false; // we do not want to show the second paragraph until the user press any key in the input

$("#userInput").on('keydown', function() {

  if(!showSecondParagraph) { // similar to "showSecondParagraph == false"
    $("#first").hide();
    $("#second").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="first">This paragraph will be displayed when the page loads but will be hide as you type something in the input</p>
<p id="second" style="display: none">This paragraph won't show until you press some key in the text box</p>

<input type="text" id="userInput">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

started = false.

if(!started) means if true.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the explanation that you are looking for:
Look like you are trying to implement something similar to the toggle function in Javascript, but using another way. You are using a variable (called "started") to remember the status of the system. Then you are checking the status and switching it between true and false each time a key is pressed.